# json.dumps() give unexpected result when passing a variable of subclass of str in python 2.7

Tags: json, python-2.7

I wrote a subclass of str like this:

```
class URL(str):
    def __init__(self, url):
        u = normalize_url(url)
        print u
        super(URL, self).__init__(string=u)
```

`normalize_url()` function is used for doing something like url encoding. Everything is ok, until I use `json.dumps()`. Here is my test code:

```
>>> u = URL('https://example.com/path contains space.html')
https://example.com/path%20contains%20space.html
>>> json.dumps(u)
'"https://example.com/path contains space.html"'
```

Why `json.dumps()` didn't give 'https://example.com/path%20contains%20space.html'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` (like other immutable objects) does it's initialization in `__new__`

Construction of an object in python roughly looks like this:

```
inst = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
cls.__init__(inst, *args, **kwargs)
```

In your example, you call `__init__`, but it is too late, the object has already been set up in `__new__`

You can however fix this!:

```
class URL(str):
    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, val):
         val = val.replace(' ', '%20')
         return super(URL, cls).__new__(cls, val)
```

Now it works!

```
>>> x = URL('foo bar')
>>> x
'foo%20bar'
>>> json.dumps(x)
'"foo%20bar"'
```

Note that I've added `__slots__ = ()` to restore the immutability that `str` had.